# mysql-connector-java update from 5 to 6 causes a timeshift

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, mysql-connector

In our java(1.8) / hibernate(4.3.2) / mysql (5.6.29-76.2) application we are using mysql-connector-java **5.1.40**. 
Timezones for all servers(java, mysql) is UTC.
When in the application we were inserting some datetimes '2016-10-26 **08:00:00**' into the DB, they were saved correctly as '2016-10-26 **08:00:00**'.
After upgrading mysql-connector-java to **6.0.4**, we get the following behavior: in the java code we insert '2016-10-26 **08:00:00**', in the DB we get '2016-10-26 **13:00:00**', when we select those values in the java app we get the correct '2016-10-26 **08:00:00**' value. However, all previously saved values get shifted into the past.

So far, we have no idea, what is causing this shift. Any ideas?

**Update**
After running multiple tests with time zones, I have noticed the following:

> Timezones for all servers(java, mysql) is UTC.
>   This was wrong, and in fact it was a BST(British Summer Time)

Other time zones (CEST, UTC, GMT+6, Asia/Almaty, GMT-6 etc.. ) were working fine, BST causes those shifts. So, I am about to make a conclusion that there's some bug related to the BST time-zone in mysql-connector.
As a workaround - switching to some other time zones.

Comment: Are you certain that the MySQL server's timezone was not changed during the update?

Comment: Mysql server was not updated, only mysql-connector-java is updated. 
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@system_time_zone, @@session.time_zone; Gives:
'SYSTEM', 'BST', 'SYSTEM'

Comment: What time zone was the application doing the insert. JDBC requires that the timezone of the JVM is used.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, it was JVM system timezone. Basically, we were taking current system time.

Comment: Came across same issue!